# How to identify the list from nested list which has only date format using python3?

Tags: python-3.x

How to identify the list from nested list which has only  date format  using python3?

```
 import re
 l=[["1","2","3"],["a","b","c"],["22/01/2019","23/01/2019"]]


for i,string in enumerate(l):
    data_cleaning_txn_date = re.findall(r"[\d]{1,2}/[\d]{1,2}/[\d]{4}",string)
    print(l)
```

> Expected Output:

```
22/01/2019
23/01/2019
```

Comment: Check my answer below!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can parse the datetime object using the [datetime.strptime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) library.
    If you can successfully parse it, print it otherwise not.

```
import re
import datetime
l=[["1","2","3"],["a","b","c"],["22/01/2019","23/01/2019"]]

#Function to parse string
def parse_datetime(date_str):

    date_obj = None
    try:
        date_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_str, "%d/%m/%Y")
    except:
        pass

    return date_obj

for items in l:
    for item in items:
        #Only if parse_datetime is succussful, print the item
        if parse_datetime(item):
            print(item)
#22/01/2019
#23/01/2019
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
l=[["1","2","3"],["a","b","c"],["22/01/2019","23/01/2019"]]

for i,string in enumerate(l):
    for j in string:
        if re.findall(r"\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4}", j):
            print(j)

the output:
22/01/2019
23/01/2019
```